# Should we write a Test Case for every Foreign Key?

Tags: java, manual-testing, test-management, test-design, database

Should I write a test case for every Foreign key in the database?

Our team is conducting a large database migration project using Java APIs, for eg. inputting CustomerSales.

And we have ProductId, VendorId, StoreId, MailCarrierId, etc.

So we are writing test cases for every foreign key column, ensuring if foreign key exists or incorrect. This will lead to 8+ foreign key cases. Its like we are retesting if Microsoft SQL Server knows to enforce its database keys constraints and foreign keys.

Is that the correct methodology? If so, We will have hundreds of foreign key cases for every table we migrate, not just CustomerSales.

Comment: How similar is each Foreign key in structure? Could you just write a method or function that can handle any Foreign Key you want to test?

Comment: a foreign key is written as similar, ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);

Comment: Can you back up a step?  What are you actually trying to test?  That the two databases are logically equal?  Or that the database conversion program itself works?

Comment: hi @KevinMcKenzie we are migrating from 1 database schema design in Oracle to a total new relational design in MSSQL

Comment: Right, but again, what are you trying to test?  The conversion process?  That the two databases are logically equal?  Or that the front end tool(s) still work after the migration?

Answer (score 2):

I would not use test cases for a database conversion project.

The task at-hand is database validation to see if foreign key constrinsta have been enforced.  This can be developed reagrdles of the conversion.  I would use database and dba tools and programs.

What to do about missing or duplicate records will depend on your target database - same vendor? same size? etc

Be careful not to get database conversion and database cleanup mixed up until you are sure you want to.  Conversely, be carefuly not to put off cleanup to post-conversion - and then never do it which is common in my experiuence.

Comment: not sure what the differences between these terms are, database conversion , database cleanup, post-conversion

Comment: cleanup: _for every foreign key column, ensuring if foreign key exists or incorrect._